# How do i get prediction accuracy when testing unknown data on a saved model in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

i have a model i have trained for binary classification, i now want to use it to predict unknown class elements.

```
     from sklearn.externals import joblib
     model = joblib.load('../model/randomForestModel.pkl')
     test_data = df_test.values # df_test is a dataframe with my test data
     output = model.predict(test_data[:,1:]) # this outputs the prediction either 1 or 0
```

I know how to get confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, classification_report given the training dataset, but in the case i do not have the train data.
i would like to get something akin to this from weka:

```
       inst#     actual  predicted error prediction
           1        1:?        1:0       0.757
```

Is it possible in Scikit-learn? if so, how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's totally possible.

1) When trying to evaluate a model that you trained, you should use a testing set. A subset from the data that you have which you did not use to train in order to evaluate the capability of your model to predict new values. With this testing set you have the true value, so you can compare result of prediction. 
You can simple use, the [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) package or cross_validation.

2) Scikit-learn provide different [metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) in order to evaluate a model. Once again you should use this metrics on a test set and not on your training set. This could lead to fake good result.

I dont see any reason why you would not be aware of the training set. But you can also use the _score method of model which you can parametrize as desire(F1 score, recall, precision).

In weka, I do not see what error prediction is. Can you explain ?

Comment: thanks, in weka it's not 'error prediction',  but actually 'error' is a separate column which when you evaluate known classes, if an incorrect prediction has been made then that column will  have a "+". back to my question, i want to use the model in a production setting hence no need for training data. i only want to test each value as it comes in, but i would like to know the probabilty/accuracy of the predicted class. I'm not sure if i have managed to articulate correctly...

Comment: I think I understood. Each classifiers in scikit learn have `predict_proba` method which display the probability for each possible class. You will then know the probability of the predicted class which will be the highest. You can find more information following this link : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba